# String concatination in angular filter with scope variables

Tags: angularjs, filter, expression

After combining value of two scope variable I wants to apply filter on the resultant output.
Let me explain more clearly where I am stuck.

```
<h2>{{scope_variable1 | filter_name}}<H2>
```

Here in my above html I have **scope_variable1** in scope which contains string value.This is working fine but I wants to combine value of two scope variables and then i wants to apply filter.

I have one more **scope_variable2** and which also contains string value now I want to concatenate both variable's value and then want to apply filter.

Is it possible to do on html element?

As I am aware of other ways to achieve like by using controller and taking third variable in scope but i want to know if it directly possible.

Comment: yes , its possible... you need to write custom filter.

Comment: Have you tried concatenating the strings and applying the filter? What's the problem? http://plnkr.co/edit/rggZoTM2y7epTBfkMNxG?p=preview

Comment: @JB Nizet Thanks. I tried this but at that time it was not working due to other reason but now I make it correct.feeling bad for such silly thing.